# Numpy Typing with specific shape and datatype

Tags: numpy, python-typing, typing

Currently i'm trying to work more with numpy typing to make my code clearer however i've somehow reached a limit that i can't currently override.

Is it possible to specify a specific shape and also the corresponding data type?
Example:

```
Shape=(4,)
datatype= np.int32
```

My attempts so far look like the following (but all just threw errors):

First attempt:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(x: np.ndarray[(4,), np.dtype[np.int32]]):
...
result -> 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

Second attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def foo(x: npt.NDArray[(4,), np.int32]):
...
result -> Too many arguments for numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]
```

Also, unfortunately, I can't find any information about it in the documentation or I only get errors when I implement it the way it is documented.

Comment: I haven't used it, but the `numpy.typing` docs has examples of specifying `dtype`, but not shape (at least not in a quick read).

Comment: Do you really want, or need, to limit the shape - in a static sense?  Are you using type along with a checker like `mypy`, or is this just for human readers?  For readers, you could just use string annotations.  Or as `numpy/scipy` functions already do - note the shape and dtype in the docs.  Usually in `numpy` code you want to specify the relation between arguments -  that one array has shape (N,) and another (N,M), but not to be so specific as to say one must be (2,3).

Comment: It must be so strict. Normally I would completely agree with your answer, but for this use case it has to be strict unfortunately, and nice would be the numpy typing as well

Comment: As long as it's only for human readers, I've found myself using annotations like `np.ndarray[Annotated[tuple[int, int], ('n', 'n')], np.dtype[np.float16]]`. It satisfies things like pyright (haven't tested mypy), but also gives some extra info for humans: in this case, that the array is 2D and square. Seems like the whole system could use some help :shrug:

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Currently, `numpy.typing.NDArray` only accepts a dtype, like so: `numpy.typing.NDArray[numpy.int32]`. You have some options though.

### Use `typing.Annotated`

[`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) allows you to create an alias for a type and to bundle some extra information with it.

In some `my_types.py` you would write all variations of shapes you want to hint:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Literal, TypeVar
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


DType = TypeVar("DType", bound=np.generic)

Array4 = Annotated[npt.NDArray[DType], Literal[4]]
Array3x3 = Annotated[npt.NDArray[DType], Literal[3, 3]]
ArrayNxNx3 = Annotated[npt.NDArray[DType], Literal["N", "N", 3]]
```

And then in `foo.py`, you can supply a numpy dtype and use them as typehint:

```py
import numpy as np
from my_types import Array4


def foo(arr: Array4[np.int32]):
    assert arr.shape == (4,)
```

MyPy will recognize `arr` to be an `np.ndarray` and will check it as such. The shape checking can be done at runtime only, like in this example with an `assert`.

If you don't like the assertion, you can use your creativity to define a function to do the checking for you.

```py
def assert_match(arr, array_type):
    hinted_shape = array_type.__metadata__[0].__args__
    hinted_dtype_type = array_type.__args__[0].__args__[1]
    hinted_dtype = hinted_dtype_type.__args__[0]
    assert np.issubdtype(arr.dtype, hinted_dtype), "DType does not match"
    assert arr.shape == hinted_shape, "Shape does not match"


assert_match(some_array, Array4[np.int32])
```

### Use `nptyping`

Another option would be to use 3th party lib [`nptyping`](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping) (yes, I am the author).

You would drop `my_types.py` as it would be of no use anymore.

Your `foo.py` would become something like:

```py
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape, Int32


def foo(arr: NDArray[Shape["4"], Int32]):
    assert isinstance(arr, NDArray[Shape["4"], Int32])
```

### Use `beartype` + `typing.Annotated`

There is also another 3th party lib called [`beartype`](https://github.com/beartype/beartype#numpy-arrays) that you could use. It can take a variant of the `typing.Annotated` approach and will do the runtime checking for you.

You would reinstate your `my_types.py` with content similar to:

```py
from beartype import beartype
from beartype.vale import Is
from typing import Annotated
import numpy as np


Int32Array4 = Annotated[np.ndarray, Is[lambda array:
    array.shape == (4,) and np.issubdtype(array.dtype, np.int32)]]
Int32Array3x3 = Annotated[np.ndarray, Is[lambda array:
    array.shape == (3,3) and np.issubdtype(array.dtype, np.int32)]]
```

And your `foo.py` would become:

```py
import numpy as np
from beartype import beartype
from my_types import Int32Array4 


@beartype
def foo(arr: Int32Array4):
    ...  # Runtime type checked by beartype.
```

### Use `beartype` + `nptyping`

You could also stack up both libraries.

Your `my_types.py` can be removed again and your `foo.py` would become something like:

```py
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape, Int32
from beartype import beartype


@beartype
def foo(arr: NDArray[Shape["4"], Int32]):
    ...  # Runtime type checked by beartype.
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray) says `numpy.typing.NDArray = numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+_ScalarType_co]]`. What is the first parameter `typing.Any` if `NDArray` only accepts a dtype?

Comment: It says: *"Can be used during runtime for typing arrays with a given dtype and unspecified shape."*, which means that shapes cannot be specified.

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/094416f7433a0bc077e472e801fe36613318c01f/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1477), you'll notice that the first parameter is called `_ShapeType`. To me, this suggests that numpy left the door open for future support of hinting shapes.

Comment: `hinted_dtype_type = array_type.__args__[0].__args__[1]` -- isn't this wrong? I think it should be `hinted_dtype_type = array_type.__args__[1]` because the type is e.g. `numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.int32]]`, so of that `.__args__[1]` is `numpy.dtype[numpy.int32]`.

Answer (score 2):

I use to proceed like this:

```
def foo(x):
    x = np.array(x, dtype=np.int32)
    if x.shape!=Shape:
        raise ValueError("Shape mismatch")
    #...
```

If you have specific problem with the shape, you should reshape before depending on which input shape you expect to have. Provide an example of your input `x` if you need help to reshape it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would be of course a workaround but I try to integrate the typing directly with python and I could not do that with your suggestion.

Comment: An `assert` is another syntax for this kind of testing.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you can put *anything* as the first type argument to np.ndarray[_ShapeLike, _DtypeLike_co].  E.g.

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Literal, cast

arr = cast(np.ndarray[Literal[4], np.dtype[np.int_]], np.arange(4))

def bar(a: np.ndarray[Literal[4], np.dtype[np.int_]]) -> None: ...
bar(arr)
```

passes type checking.  Most numpy functions that change the dimension or size of an array, however, don't necessarily know how to handle different axes and sizes in typing.  As a result something like:  `arr[:]` will lose the shape type information from arr.

Also it's worth checking out [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) introducing `TypeVarTuple`.  While numpy has not implemented shape as a `TypeVarTuple` (IIRC, as of writing, it was implemented as a `TypeVar` bound to `Any`), that PEP suggests several ways you might type your arrays while numpy still accepts `Any` as the shape.  The main point is that you ought to use `tuple[Literal[4]]` in the above example instead.