NumPy Typing of Array (Vector, Matrix) of Floats
What's the proper way to add type hints to a function with NumPy arrays?
Specifically hint the types are vectors / matrices of any supported float.
def MyFun( myVectorFloat: <Typing>, myMatrixFloat: <Typing> ):
  some code...

So I want to type hint myVectorFloat as a vector (len(myVectorFloat.shape) == 1) and myMatrixFloat as a matrix (len(myMatrixFloat.shape) == 2).
I want support for Float16, Float32 and Float64.
What's it the proper way to achieve that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71109838/numpy-typing-with-specific-shape-and-datatype
Check this question please

@BogdanShevchenko, I am aware of it. It doesn't answer the whole question of mine. I posted mine after looking at it.

Annotated[npt.NDArray[Union[np.float16, np.float34, np.float64]], Literal["N"]] for the vector, same with Lineral["N", "N"] for the matrix?

@Marat, But this uses things beyond NumPy.

@Royi yeah, they come from the standard typing module. Why is it a problem?

@Marat, Could you write it as an answer? I thought one could achieve everything using NumPy's typing.

Checking Jake Stevens-Haas's answer in the question linked by @BogdanShevchenko above, the following should be possible in NumPy 2.1.0 and above: my_vec_float: np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.dtype[np.float16 | np.float32 | np.float64]] and my_mat_float: np.ndarray[tuple[int, int], np.dtype[np.float16 | np.float32 | np.float64]].

@simon, Indeed, I saw it before posting. I didn't get how can I set the dimensions to have any length (Vector of any size).
